# hierarchical sum in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

This is a simplified version of a problem I am encountering in PostgreSQL.

I have the following table **A**:

**[ ID** *INTEGER*  **| VALUE** *NUMERIC(10,2)* **| PARENT** *INTEGER* **]**

Where 'PARENT' is a self-referencing FK to column ID.

The table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE A(ID INTEGER IDENTITY, VALUE NUMERIC(10,2), PARENT INTEGER)                                    
ALTER  TABLE A ADD CONSTRAINT FK FOREIGN KEY (PARENT) REFERENCES A(ID)
```

This simple table allows one to define tree data structures of arbitrary depth. Now I need to write a SQL (I prefer not to use server-side PL-SQL) that reports for each node, the total value of the sub-tree "hanging" under it. For instance, with the following table:

```
|  ID  | VALUE | PARENT |
-------------------------
|   1  | NULL  | NULL   |
|   2  | 3.50  |    1   |
|   3  | NULL  | NULL   |
|   4  | NULL  |    3   |
|   5  | 1.50  |    4   |
|   6  | 2.20  |    4   |
```

I should get the following result set:

```
| ID  |  Total-Value-of-Subtree |
|  1  |                  3.50   |
|  2  |                  3.50   |
|  3  |                  3.70   |
|  4  |                  3.70   |
|  5  |                  1.50   |
|  6  |                  2.20   |
```

For simplicitly, you can assume that only leaf nodes have values, non-leaf nodes always have a value of **NULL** in the **VALUE** column. Is there a way to do this in SQL, even utilizing PostgreSQL-specific extensions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can use recursive CTEs (Common Table Expression) to walk trees in your queries.

Here are two relevant links into the docs:

- [Syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH)
- [Examples](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html)

**EDIT**

Since there is no subselect required it might run a little better on a larger dataset than Arion's query.

```
WITH RECURSIVE children AS (
    -- select leaf nodes
    SELECT id, value, parent
        FROM t
        WHERE value IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    -- propagate values of leaf nodes up, adding rows 
    SELECT t.id, children.value, t.parent
        FROM children JOIN t ON children.parent = t.id
)
SELECT id, sum(value) 
    FROM children 
    GROUP BY id   -- sum up appropriate rows
    ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        t.ID,
        t.VALUE,
        t.PARENT
    FROM
        t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT NULL FROM t AS t2 WHERE t2.PARENT=t.ID
        )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        t.ID,
        COALESCE(t.VALUE,CTE.VALUE),
        t.PARENT
    FROM
        t
        JOIN CTE
            ON CTE.PARENT=t.ID
)
SELECT
    CTE.ID,
    SUM(CTE.VALUE)
FROM
    CTE
GROUP BY
    CTE.ID
ORDER BY 
    ID;
```

This will start with the children that has no children. Then go up the tree to the parents. The result will be like this:

```
1   3.50
2   3.50
3   3.70
4   3.70
5   1.50
6   2.20
```