# Recursive sum of values in an hierarchical table in Oracle 10g

Tags: view, oracle10g, sum, hierarchical

Assuming I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_EXAMPLE ( ID NUMBER , PARENT NUMBER , VALUE NUMBER );

Insert into MY_EXAMPLE (ID,PARENT,VALUE) values (1,null,100);
Insert into MY_EXAMPLE (ID,PARENT,VALUE) values (2,1,50);
Insert into MY_EXAMPLE (ID,PARENT,VALUE) values (3,null,0);
Insert into MY_EXAMPLE (ID,PARENT,VALUE) values (4,2,1000);
Insert into MY_EXAMPLE (ID,PARENT,VALUE) values (5,1,1);

|id   |parent   |value   |
|1    |null     |100     |
|2    |1        |50      |
|3    |null     |0       |
|4    |2        |1000    |
|5    |1        |1       |
```

I need to create a view (which should perform well) with the same number of rows but giving the row's plus the children's value summed. Many levels are possible as well as many children.

```
|id   |parent   |value   |
|1    |null     |1151    | (sum of 1 + 2 + 4 + 5)
|2    |1        |1050    | (sum of 2 + 4)
|3    |null     |0       | (only 3 because has no children)
|4    |2        |1000    | (only 4 because has no children)
|5    |1        |1       | (only 5 because has no children)
```

ps.: I tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191885/hierarchical-sum-in-postgresql) but it didn't work in Oracle 10g first because the keyword RECURSIVE is not supported and second because it won't allow recursive WITH ("forward or recursive reference of a query name in WITH clause is not allowed").

Also I couldn't figure out a way to do it with CONNECT BY that includes the id and parent columns and gives me the whole table (in my attempts I always had to use START WITH).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a recursive function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION RECURSIVE_ADD(
    ROOT_ID IN NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  TOTAL NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT   SUM(VALUE)
    INTO TOTAL
    FROM (
      (
        SELECT VALUE FROM MY_EXAMPLE WHERE ID = ROOT_ID
      )
    UNION
        (
          SELECT recursive_add(id) FROM my_example WHERE parent = root_id
        ));
  RETURN total;
END;

select id, parent, value, RECURSIVE_ADD(id) from my_example;
```

Make sure you don't have a cycle in your data (for example, if you set the parent of 1 to 2) otherwise this will never terminate. There are other ways to do this in newer versions of Oracle, but this will work in 10g.

Comment: I might accept your answer but the truth is I need a better performance. I'm considering to calculate and store the sum using triggers.