# Generate table of contents indexes based on parent-child relationships

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a table of named `task` having self relation to accomplish parent-child relationship.

Here is the structure of the table:

```
task (id, name, parent_id)
```

Any task can have `n` children.

Now in my view I have to show the tasks in table of contents format with nth level nesting like this:

```
1. Grandfather

     1.1. Father

 1.2 Mother

    1.2.1 First Child

    1.2.1 Second Child

2. Grandfather's brother

 2.1 Grandfather's brothers son 

3. Grandfather's brother's wife
```

For clarity I have named these tasks for human relations just to show nested hierarchy levels.

What I do is that I select all the tasks from my database and start iterating them over like this:

```
foreach($tasks as $task)
{
//Get the hierarchy level here and print its index for example 1.1.2
}
```

I don't know how to order them in 1,2,3 levels because any task at index zero may be have its actual position to be 3.1.2 for example.

Can this be done at code level? 
Or Any SQL suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: MySQL or Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Postgresql...removed MySQL if it had issues with questions

Comment: What version of postgres?

Comment: You have to use ctes. Here is an example, just replace the sum by the concated string you want to get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191885/hierarchical-sum-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

In postgres you can write recursive queries to read all or part of a hierarchical data structure.

```
CREATE TABLE task
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT,
  name text,
  parent_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT task_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT task_parent_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
      REFERENCES public.task (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

insert into task values
(1, 'grandfather', null),
(2, 'father', 1),
(3, 'mother', 1),
(4, 'first child', 3),
(5, 'second child', 3),
(6, 'grandfather''s brother', null),
(7, 'grandfather''s brother''s son', 6),
(8, 'grandfather''s brother''s wife', null);

with recursive relations(relation_id, parent_id, path) as(
    select id as relation_id, null::integer as parent, ARRAY[id]::integer[], from task where parent_id is null
    union 
    select id, task.parent_id, path || id from relations
    join task on task.parent_id = relation_id

)
select * from relations
order by path
```

Output is:

```
relation_id parent_id   path
1                       {1}
2           1           {1,2}
3           1           {1,3}
4           3           {1,3,4}
5           3           {1,3,5}
6                       {6}
7           6           {6,7}
8                       {8}
```

Now in your for loop you just need an array that increments the number for each new element in the path and when the size goes down by one reset the counter.

This could probably be done in SQL as well

Another option to consider is using ltree instead of a parent_id for storing your relationships. That would get rid of the need for the CTE

Comment: ltree can come very handy for tree manipulation.
(ex: Grandfather.Father.SecondChild is your new key that can match a Grandfather.Father.* query )
Here http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/173-Using-LTree-to-Represent-and-Query-Hierarchy-and-Tree-Structures.html is explained how to simply add a trigger so based on a application using id, parent_id model you have an up to date matching ltree field.